# Kubernetes command arguments being ignored

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod

when running specific command from linux terminal command is the following:

```
/opt/front/arena/sbin/ads_start  ads  -db_server vmazfassql01 -db_name Test1
```

In regular docker compose yaml file we define it like this:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/front/arena/sbin/ads_start", "ads" ]
command: ["-db_server vwmazfassql01","-db_name Test1"]
```

Then I tried to convert it to Kubernetes

```
command: ["/opt/front/arena/sbin/ads_start","ads"]
args: ["-db_server vwmazfassql01","-db_name Test1"]
```

or without quotes for args

```
command: ["/opt/front/arena/sbin/ads_start","ads"]
args: [-db_server vwmazfassql01,-db_name Test1]
```

but I got errors for both cases:

```
Unknown parameter value '-db_server vwmazfassql01'
Unknown parameter value '-db_name Test1'
```

I then tried to remove dashes from args but then it seems those values are being ignored and not set up. During the Initialization values process, during the container start, those properties seem to have they default values e.g. db_name: "ads". At least that is how it is printed out in the log during the Initialization.

I tried few more possibilities:
To define all of them in command:

```
command:
  - /opt/front/arena/sbin/ads_start
  - ads
  - db_server vwmazfassql01
  - db_name Test1
```

To define them in little bit different way:

```
command: ["/opt/front/arena/sbin/ads_start","ads"]
args:
  - db_server vwmazfassql01
  - db_name Test1


command: ["/opt/front/arena/sbin/ads_start","ads"]
args: [db_server vwmazfassql01,db_name Test1]
```

again they are being ignored, and not being set up.
Am I doing something wrong? How I can make some workaround for this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try separating the args, following the documentation example (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#run-a-command-in-a-shell)

Something like:

```
command: ["/opt/front/arena/sbin/ads_start", "ads"]
args: ["-db_server", "vwmazfassql01", "-db_name", "Test1"]
```

Or maybe, it would work even like this and it looks more clean:

```
command: ["/opt/front/arena/sbin/ads_start"]
args: ["ads", "-db_server", "vwmazfassql01", "-db_name", "Test1"]
```

This follows the general approach of running an external command from code (a random example is python subprocess module) where you specify each single piece of the command that means something on its own.

Comment: bravo! You are real K8S expert :-) This resolved this issue and parameters are set.
I do it using the first method!
If I may please ask you just one more thing - I also have one more paramter `-unicode` which I didn't mention but that is also needed and only that cannot be set and again Unknown error is displayed when  I try to set it like this:
`args: ["-unicode","1","-db_server", "vwmazfassql01".....`  or like this `args: ["-unicode","-db_server", "vwmazfassql01".....` can you please assist me for that one as well? THANKS

Comment: Again with unknown parameter error? Same error as before? And if you try to run the command with that parameter from linux terminal, it works without any problem?

Comment: Yeah, just that one. This property is only the specific one since it does not have "value", only the "key" value which is "unicode" and in that manner Unicode is enabled for the application. Using the linux terminal it works. Do you by any chance know what can be an issue?

Comment: If it has only a key, then the first example, adding a "1" seems wrong to me, but the second one where you simply add "-unicode" in the args (in the right order your application expects it) should work in theory, if the concatenation of command and all the args together creates the same command you run on your linux console. Does it works with the docker compose?

Comment: I must check double check it for docker compose since I do not have it currently. I will get back to you tomorrow. Thank you once again!